# Disable event listener inside a textbox with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add event handlers for up,down,left and right key but I don't want them to be fired when a user accidentally hits them while typing inside a text box. I have written the jsfiddle to illustrate the issue. 
I have tried to check the events when inside the textbox and stop propagation but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) 
{
    switch(event.which) {
        case 37:  // left
            $("#left-arrow").show();
            break;
        case 38:  // up
              $("#up-arrow").show();
            break;
        case 40:  // down
              $("#down-arrow").show();
            break;
        case 39:  // right
              $("#right-arrow").show();
    }
});

$("#textbox1").keyup(function()
{
    var textinput = $('#textbox1').val();
    $("#textbox2").val(textinput);
    $(document).keyup(function (event) {
        var keycode2 = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if ( keycode2 == '37' || keycode2 == '38' || keycode2 == '39' || keycode2 == '40') {
          event.stopPropagation();  
        }
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44h6n8q2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `stopPropagation` on the event you get *from the original
`keyup` callback*:

```
$("#textbox1").keyup(function(event) {
    var textinput = $('#textbox1').val();
    $("#textbox2").val(textinput);
    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keycode == 37 || keycode == 38 || keycode == 39 || keycode == 40) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```